# Microservice with FastAPI and Flask apps in Docker with NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

I have a docker-compose object with next structure:

- nginx
- FastAPI
- Flask

I am using nginx to control frontend part (Flask) and backend (FastAPI) on different routs on one web server.

I have a subdomain for FastAPI (api.localhost) and main domain (localhost) for Flask instance. Nginx server works fine, but when I go to api.localhost, it shows me the page from localhost. It seems that subdomain part is ignored and it just shows Flask page.

How can I make Flask ignore subdomain part to work properly in such architecture?

Here is my nginx.config file

```
http {
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://ux:9000;
          }
      }
    
    server {
        listen 80; 
        server_name api.localhost;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://api:8000;
    }

}
```

My docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: nginx
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
          - ./nginx/data:/data

    api:
        image: python3.8-alpine
        container_name: api
        build: ./api
        command: gunicorn app.main:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
        environment:
          - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://$POSTGRESDB_USER:$POSTGRESDB_PWD@db:5432/$POSTGRESDB_DB
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
    
    ux:
        image: python3.8-alpine
        container_name: ux
        restart: always
        build: ./ux
        command: gunicorn app.main:app --bind 0.0.0.0:9000
        ports:
          - 9000:9000
```

I tried to use subdomain_matching=False for Flask app instance, but it did not work. If I do not include ux object in docker-compose file, subdomains work properly

Comment: are you mapping the subdomain to localhost in /etc/hosts? (assuming you're using linux or macos)